# Extract a decimal number from a sentence using a QRegularExpression

Tags: c++, regex, qt, qregularexpression

I am currently trying to extract the following decimal number:

> 2453.6756667756

from the following sentence:

> ID: 1 x: 1202 y: 2453.6756667756 w: 242

I am using this code:

```
regularExpression.setPattern("(\\d+)(?:\\s*)(w:)")
```

However it gives me this result:

> 6756667756

which is not correct at all.

Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
\d+\.\d+(?=\s*w:)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mU7zZ7/2)

In Qt:

```
regularExpression.setPattern("\\d+\\.\\d+(?=\\s*w:)")
```

The regex matches:

- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `\.` - a literal dot
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `(?=\s*w:)` - a positive lookahead making sure there is zero or more whitespace symbols after the last digit matched and a `w` followed by `:` (but this substring is not consumed, just checked for presence since lookaheads are *zero-width assertions*).

You can use a [simpler regex](https://regex101.com/r/mU7zZ7/3) without a lookahead with a capturing group:

```
(\d+\.\d+)\s*w:
```

Then, the value will be in Group 1.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help ! I did not know that this excellent website existed. It's going to be very useful !

Comment: Just note that regex101.com does not support Qt regex syntax. To make sure these will work in Qt, do not use lazy quantifiers (`??`, `*?`, `+?`, `{1,5}?`) and make sure you use `/s` modifier to force `.` to match newlines as in Qt a `.` matches a newline. Well, for basic patterns like this one, it should do.

Comment: One last question. Do you recommend me a particular tutorial which talks about regular expressions ? How to be as good as you are in regular expressions ? It is something very useful in developing.

Comment: Here is my usual answer to this question: I do not know your level of regex knowledge :) so that I can only suggest doing all lessons at [regexone.com](http://regexone.com/), reading through [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info), [regex SO tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) (with many other links to great online resources), and the community SO post called [What does the regex mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean). And the most efficient is to answer regex questions here on SO. :)

Comment: Well, I am really a beginner in regular expressions. However, I think that all your advice are going to help me a lot. Thank you so much ! :)